# How to determine the direction of the wave with the wave vector at Gamma point in the Brillouin zone center?

Tags: solid-state-physics

In the Brillouin zone, such as M point in the Brillouin zone of hexagon lattice, we can determine the direction of this wave vector in the real space; however, for Gamma point,I can't determine the direction in the real space. Does anyone know how to determine? or the physical significance of Gamma point in the real space?

Comment: The $\Gamma$ point has no direction because it corresponds to all of the lattice points being in phase with each other (i.e. there's no relative displacement within the crystal).

Comment: So if I excite a state of the energy band at the Gamma point, how to judge the                 direction the wave propagates?

Comment: You can only excite the $\Gamma$ point in the optical branch which requires at least 2 atoms in the basis. In this case the atoms *within* the unit cell oscillate with respect to each other, but the same atom in all unit cells do not move with respect to each other. So there's no wave propagation...

Comment: @lemon Your answer is fine for phonons.  For electrons, you have to neglect your parenthetical comment.